# Change the 'back-order' text in our back-order woocommerce email

Tags: email, woocommerce

We are using Woocommerce and the Flatsome theme for our webshop. Some of our products are not on stock, but customers can back order them. They receive a confirmation email with under the product that is not on stock the text 'back-order' (or 'Nabesteld: 1' in Dutch) - see screenshot.

How can we change this 'back-order' ('Nabesteld: 1') text into something else?

Thank you in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in two ways:

1. Add a filter to `woocommerce_backordered_item_meta_name` (receives the backorder text and the product as arguments).
2. Add a translation for `'Backordered'` in the `'woocommerce'` domain.

Comment: Hi Dan,

Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain a little bit more what you mean with 'woocommerce' domain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Vildan, you can enter the domain as a parameter if you translate it in code, or it'll be one of the fields you enter when using a translation plugin. You'd just enter `woocommerce` for that.